# How would to make image flow down without creating all the space below it. (Would like it to just move down into next heading if needed.)

Tags: html, css, image

My img won't integrate down into the page.

css for img:

```
dee {
display: block;
float: right;
border: 6px double grey;
width: 210px;
height: auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
background-color: #cad3de;
```

}

Img is nested within a section is this the problem?

[Img of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu4Zd.png)

Comment: the question was not clear. Do you want to push down the image?

Answer (score -1):

set margin: 0; on the img .. or your section has padding maybe.